# PostgreSQL триггер на дату больше текущей

Tags: sql, postgresql, триггер

Пытаюсь сделать триггер на дату, если больше текущей, то видать ошибку, а если меньше или текущая, то разрешить.

У меня триггер разрешает выставлять в текущую дату, но почему-то запрещает выставлять на прошедшие дни. Что можно добавить к моему триггеру ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION sch.no_more1()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin 
if(new.date > current_date)
   then raise exception 'Запрещено на будущее ставить';
   end if;
 return new;
   end

$BODY$;
```

Триггерное действие:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ocenk_no_more1
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON sch.table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sch.no_more1();
```

UPD: Очень странно конечно, я все перепроверил (удалил и создал заново) и оно нормально заработало - запрещает на будущее, но разрешает на текущее и прошедшие

Comment: *удалил и создал заново) и оно нормально заработало* Зело похоже на опечатку - `<>` вместо `>`...

Comment: В общем-то здесь не нужен триггер вовсе, check constraint достаточно. `create temp table foo (d date check (d <= current_date));`